# How can I display messages in Front (instead of alerts) when verifying Forms (JS only)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have already a form verification in JS, that allows for an alert display in Front when one or several values are incorrect (eg. Password too short, needs at least one number).

I want to change these alerts to messages that will display in an HTML p above the affected input.

I have the following in HTML:

```
<form id="formNew">
        <div>
            <p id="msgPseudo"></p>
            <label for="pseudo">Pseudo</label>
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="pseudo" id="pseudo" required>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p id="msgEmail"></p>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <br>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" minlength="8" maxlength="30" required>
        </div>

        <div>
            <p id="msgPass"></p>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="*******" id="password" required>
        </div>

        <div>

            <p id="msgPassRep"></p>
            <label for="passwordRepeat">Confirm password</label>
            <br>
            <input type="password"  placeholder="*******" id="confirm_password" required> 
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Create an account">
        </div>
</form>
```

and the following in JS:

```
function valideForm(e) {

  e.preventDefault();


  var valPseudo = document.getElementById("pseudo").value;
  var valPassword = document.getElementById("password").value;
  var valEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var errorsPass = [];
  var errorsPseudo = [];
  var emailRegex = /.+@.+\..+/;


  
  let letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  let numbers = '0123456789'
  let letterCount = 0
  let numberCount = 0

  for (let character of valPseudo.toLowerCase()) {
    if (letters.includes(character))
      ++letterCount
    else if (numbers.includes(character))
      ++numberCount
    else
      return false //A non [a-zA-Z0-9] character was present
  }

  if (letterCount + numberCount > 40)
  errorsPseudo.push("Pseudo is too long") //The name is too long
  if (letterCount + numberCount < 5)
  errorsPseudo.push("Pseudo is too short")//The name is too short
  if (letterCount < 1)
  errorsPseudo.push("Pseudo needs at least one letter") //There aren't enough [a-zA-Z] characters
  if (numberCount < 1)
  errorsPseudo.push("Pseudo needs at least one number") //There aren't enough [0-9] characters

  if (errorsPseudo.length) {
    alert(errorsPseudo);
  }



if(emailRegex.test(valEmail) == false) {
    alert ("veuillez entrer un E-mail valide");
    return false;
}


if (!valPassword) {
  alert("Password is empty");
}
if((valPassword.length < 8)) {
  errorsPass.push("Password should be at least 8 characters")
}
if((valPassword.length > 30)) {
  errorsPass.push("Password should not exceed 30 characters")
}
if (!/[A-Z]/.test(valPassword)) {
  errorsPass.push("Password should have at least 1 uppercase")
}
if (!/[a-z]/.test(valPassword)) {
  errorsPass.push("Password should have at least 1 lowercase")
}
if (!/[0-9]/.test(valPassword)) {
  errorsPass.push("Password should have at least 1 number")
}
if (!/(?=.[$#%£&§@])/.test(valPassword)) {
  errorsPass.push("Password should have at least 1 special character")
}
if (errorsPass.length) {
    alert(errorsPass);
}


var password = document.getElementById("password");
var confirm_password = document.getElementById("confirm_password");

function validatePassword(){
  if(password.value != confirm_password.value) {
    confirm_password.setCustomValidity("passwords aren't the same");
  } else {
    confirm_password.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}

password.onchange = validatePassword;
confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword;
  
}

document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].addEventListener('submit', valideForm);
```

I want to change the alerts display in Pseudo, Email and Password tests, as well as the .setCustomValidity for Password confirmation...
TO messages that will appear in HTML Front at the `<p></p>` location above each corresponding input.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a prompt text after the input box, such as the < p > tag. When the input content changes (such as
$("# password"). change (function () {$("P"). text)("messages ")})
)

Comment: How about in pure JS? What would it look it for a function?